# npm 5 install folder without using symlink

Tags: npm

Before publishing my node library, I could use the [advice the npm documentation wrote about](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#before-publishing-make-sure-your-package-installs-and-works):

> To test a local install, go into some other folder, and then do:
>
> cd ../some-other-folder
>
> npm install ../my-package

Prior to version 5 of npm, I had no problem as it produce what I expected, ie a folder with the output of what I will publish.

However, using npm 5, it now creates a symlink to my local project as described in the npm documentation:

> npm install :
>
> Install the package in the directory as a symlink in the current
>   project. Its dependencies will be installed before it's linked. If
>    sits inside the root of your project, its dependencies may be
>   hoisted to the toplevel node_modules as they would for other types of
>   dependencies.

How can I use the "old" way to install local project? Or is there a new way to check if my library is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use [https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-local) npm module.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @HardikModha :)

Comment: I tried using install-local, but it also creates symlinks so @HardikModha's solution doesn't work 100%.  It also has the undesirable side effect of not installing the dependencies of the local dependencies.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `npm pack` + `npm install` (as suggested by *install-local* package)

```
npm pack <path-to-local-package>
npm install <package-version.tgz>
```

This will effectively copy your local package to node_modules.
Note that this will package only production relevant files (those listed in the [files](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) section of your package.json). So, you can install it in a test app under the package own directory. Something like this:

```
my-package
  package.json
  test
    test-app
      package.json
      node_modules
        my-package
```

Assuming that `test` dir is not included in the `files` in my-package/package.json.

This works the same way with npm 5 and older versions.

Comment: Is there a better way?  In my setup I have all of my packages at the same level in my repo.  I specify depenencies by doing npm install --save ../otherpackage in the mainpackage directory.  Before it just copied ../otherpackage to mainpackage/node_modules/otherpackage, now it creates a symlink at that location that points to ../../otherpackage.  My problem is that when there are symlinks in mainpackage/node_modules, it blows up nodemon w/ an ENOSPC error.  Having to create a package with pack, then npm install the tgz file causes a problem for automated deployment.

Comment: Just tried this and it does not work, as otherpackage has a local dependency on ../yetanotherpackage.  I get the error 'Could not install from from "yetanotherpackage" as it does not contain a package.json file.'

Answer (score 0):

I wrote npm-install-offline which allows you to install npm packages from a local repository or folder. By default it copies the folder on install but you can also choose to symlink.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-offline

```
npx npm-install-offline ../some-package
```

Or

```
npx npm-install-offline my-npm-package --repo ./my-offline-npm
```

It also will install the package dependencies which npm does not do with local packages.